# How to input test case in c++ code in google code jam

Tags: c++, linux

I tried solving a problem in the Google Code Jam Practice Page [Minimum Scalar Product](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p0) and i have the program written in c++ and i read in the FAQ page that we have to test our programs with the .in test file placed on the practice page for download but i don't know how and i use UBUNTU 12.04 LTS & please i am participating in the contest for the first time..So any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks In Advance

I tried

```
    #include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numCase;
cin >> numCase;
int i, j, n;
long long c;
for (i = 0; i < numCase; i++)
{
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long> array1, array2;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        array1.push_back(c);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cin >> c;
        array2.push_back(c);
    }
    sort(array1.begin(), array1.end());
    sort(array2.begin(), array2.end(), greater<long long>());
    long long ans = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        ans += (array1[j] * array2[j]);
    cout << "Case #" << (i+1) << ": " << ans << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) and [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/)
as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.in");
    ofstream fout("output.out");

    //-- check if the files were opened successfully 
    if (!fin.is_open()) cout << "input.in was not open successfully" << endl;
    if (!fout.is_open()) cout << "output.out was not open successfully" << endl;
    int numCase;
    fin >> numCase;
    int i, j, n;
    long long c;
    for (i = 0; i < numCase; i++)
    {
        fin >> n;
        vector<long long> array1, array2;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fin >> c;
            array1.push_back(c);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fin >> c;
            array2.push_back(c);
        }
        sort(array1.begin(), array1.end());
        sort(array2.begin(), array2.end(), greater<long long>());
        long long ans = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            ans += (array1[j] * array2[j]);
        fout << "Case #" << (i + 1) << ": " << ans << endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

You can treat `fin` and `fout` as `cin`, so instead of reading the input from the console, you read the input from the file `in.txt`. Instead of writing to the console using `cout` you write to `output.out` using `fout`.

Comment: Check the update, and notice that you will submit your answer by uploading output.out file.

Comment: So this reads the input from the in.txt 1 by 1...Thanks. Could u help me place it in the code i gave you above...Just for better Understanding

Comment: Yes just like the console, but from a file. You're welcome :)

Comment: Why not just pipe the I/O to a file,  while executing?

Answer (score 0):

The general format for test cases are:

```
int t;   

cin >> t; 

while (t--)        (
{
    //code here
}
```

So we make a variable for our test cases and ask the user to input a value for it... then we make a while loop which checks if the value of t > 0 and decrements the value by 1 every time)
Hope I helped! :D